# How to get a field's value by joining multiple querysets in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to display images in a list based on certain conditions.

To that end, I have been trying to create a queryset join of a set of models (as shown below):

**models.py**

```
class ModeOfTransport(models.Model):
    mode_of_transport = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=4...


class Route(models.Model):
    route_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    route_start = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='route_start')
    route_end = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='route_end')


class RouteLeg(models.Model):
    route_leg_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    route_id = models.ForeignKey(Route, related_name='route_hdr')
    leg_start = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='leg_start')
    leg_end = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='leg_start')
    mode_of_tptn = models.ForeignKey(ModeOfTransport, related_name='route_tptn_mode')


class ImageType(models.Model):
    image_type_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=1)
    image_type = models.CharField(max_length=4)


class RouteImage(models.Model):
    image_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    image_name = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    image_type = models.ForeignKey(ImageType)
    image_route = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/route_images/')
```

From a list of existing routes (a generic listview), I am trying to create a further drilldown like this:

**views.py**

```
def graf_display_route(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        route_grafiks = RouteLeg.objects.all().filter(route_id=pk)
        return render(request, 'route_grafiks.html', {'route_grafiks': route_grafiks})
```

Now in order to get to the image field (RouteImage.image_route), I tried the following to get the image_type and then the image itself:

```
qs_mode_of_tptn = ImageType.objects.filter(image_type_id__in= route_graphics.values_list('mode_of_tptn', flat=True))
```

The result (on printing the list of resultant queryset) I can see in the terminal as:

```
[<ImageType: ImageType object (2)>, <ImageType: ImageType object (3)>]>
```

Next, using the queryset `qs_mode_of_tptn` when I use another qset, I get the image table fields (model "RouteImage"):

```
qs_route_image = RouteImage.objects.filter(image_id__in= qs_mode_of_tptn.values_list('image_type_id', flat=True))
```

And this is what I get in the terminal:

```
[<RouteImage: RouteImage object (2)>, <RouteImage: RouteImage object (3)>]>
```

The purpose of my doing this is to figure out **how to get the image** from the model `RouteImage` based on the queryset result.

To further clarify, I have done the mapping for images in the following manner:

| Field | Road | Rail | Air |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MoT (Mode of Transportation) | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Image Type | 1 | 2 | 3 |

My goal is to seek the image like this:

```
Get the "MoT (Model - RouteLeg)" -> Get "Image Type (Model - ImageType)" -> Get the "Image (Model - RouteImage)"
```

So, if the MoT is Road (1), get the ImageType (with a value "1") and then get the RouteImage (for image_type == 1).

Can I really get the images based on the above scenario? If not, can you please suggest a way to do just that.

### Edit

As you advised, I have made changes to the `qs`s as under:

a. `qs_mode_of_tptn = ImageType.objects.filter(image_type__in=route_graphics.values_list('mode_of_tptn__mode_of_transport', flat=True))`

b. `collect_images = RouteImage.objects.filter(image_type__in=qs_mode_of_tptn.values_list('image_type_id', flat=True))`

And using the first two `qs`s (which are returning the **text** values of the key fields - *ROAD*, *RAIL* etc), **qs** `collect_images` is returning the fields (including the **image** fields) now.

Comment: To clarify how the images relate to the routes.. Shouldnt `ImageType.image_type` be a foreign key to `ModeOfTransport`?

Comment: What I thought was, matching the value of `ModeOfTransport` to that of the `ImageType.image_type` should be enough to get to the image field. To test, I initialized a variable `var_image=1` and ran test code like `test_image = RouteImage.objects.filter(image_id=var_image).first()`. When passed to the template like `return render(request, 'route_grafiks.html', {'route_grafiks': route_grafiks, 'test_image': test_image})`, I am able to populate the template field!! So **this was how I had based my scenario**. My problem is how to get the `image_id`? I think I need to change my logic. Pls help.

Comment: So to clarify this.. You want to display a list of `RouteLeg` objects and want to display the matching `RouteImage` while the matching happens with "mode of transport"?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. What I tried was this: Created _qs_ `qs_mode_of_tptn = ImageType.objects.filter(image_type_id__in=route_graphics.values_list('mode_of_tptn_id', flat=True))`. And then used it to further filter down to the image field using another _qs_ as `collect_images = RouteImage.objects.filter(image_type_id__in=qs_mode_of_tptn.values_list('image_type_id', flat=True))`. Using `for..loop` I can access the image files. But for no. of **route leg** more than **One** I get more than **One** image in the **same cell** of the table. So long story short, itsn't working. **Help!!**

Comment: Sorry again. Yes, to confirm your second comment, that's **exactly** what I am trying to get to.

Comment: Don't you want to match `ModeOfTransport.mode_of_transport` (the string) to `ImageType.image_type`? I think you are trying to match the IDs which probably accidentally producde some hits as they can be the same integers?

Comment: Pls see my **edit**. For the last qs `collect_images` the field value comparison had to be done on the `id`s (`image_type_id`) as the **FK** `image_type ` of model **RouteImage** points to the pk field of model `ImageType` (otherwise it was returning a **blank list**). However, I am still getting multiple images in the **same cell**. How can I combine (or send) multiple **querysets** to the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a `dict` with the `image_type` as key so that you can map the images to a certain mode of transportation. Note that if you use [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for `mode_of_tptn` Django will already join the corresponding table so there will be no addional lookups. To get the images by type you can use [a query that spans over the relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
# your view
def graf_display_route(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        route_grafiks_qs = RouteLeg.objects.all().filter(route_id=pk).select_related("mode_of_tptn")
        
        # build a list of the modes of transport without additional query
        modes_of_tpn = [rg.mode_of_tptn.mode_of_transport for rg in route_grafiks_qs]

        # filter images for image type
        image_qs = RouteImage.objects.filter(image_type__image_type__in=modes_of_tpn)
        # build a dict of images with type as key
        images = {i.image_type.image_type: i for i in image_qs}

        route_grafiks = []
        for rg in route_grafiks_qs:
            rg.image = images[rg.mode_of_tptn.mode_of_transport]
            route_grafiks.append(rg)

        return render(request, 'route_grafiks.html', {
            'route_grafiks': route_grafiks,
        })

# in your template
{% for r in route_grafiks %}
    {{ r.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am getting error `in_bulk() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image_type__image_type__in'`.

Comment: Sorry that was an error... should just be `filter()`

Comment: Sorry, but now the page is absolut blank (other than the table headers).

Comment: I think values are not getting `append`ed correctly because if I send the qs `route_grafiks_qs` to the template (instead of **list** `route_grafiks`), the route leg values get displayed in the page table. But no images.

Comment: Another typo :/ Should be ` for rg in route_grafiks_qs:` of course..

Comment: Still the same result. Tried to print the field / values in qs `route_grafiks`, I find that there are no field references in it (for images) except for those in model `RouteLeg`. For example, if I try to get values like `for x in route_grafiks:` `print('Field value : ' + str(x.image_type_id))`, the browser comes up with error: `'RouteLeg' object has no attribute 'image_type_id'`. _Whereas_, with field `mode_of_tptn`, it comes up with the value correctly (ROAD / RAIL for a **two leg route**). So, are the image fields really getting appended to `route_grafiks`?

Comment: As in the code above the attribute being set is `image`, therefore it should `x.image`  yhou are looking for...

Comment: You are right, using `print('Field value : ' + str(x.image.image_route))` now I have the **images** (path and image names). So what is missing here?

Comment: If you have the images whats missing?

Comment: I was missing **the images**. And the reason for it was _again_ I forgot to use the key `image` in my template (_stupid_ of me). The routes are now placed exactly as they should **including the images**. I don't want to say my eyes wer glazed (but they are!!). BUt my hats off for your perseverance and zeal to help. Thanks so very much.